# Why doesn't my overlay show in some DX11 games

Tags: directx

I'm developing an overlay by hooking DX11 APIs. Now it shows in some DX11 games but doesn't in some others. Also, it shows in some scenes and doesn't in some others of the same DX11 games.

Does anyone know what the problem it can be? How can I do debugging on it?

I can supply further information if you would like to know more.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific...

Answer (score 0):

Depends where you are hooking your overlay.  If you hook Present(), it should show up on the backbuffer.  Also be sure your state is saved & restored properly.  Direct3D 11 doesn't have native state blocks, so you have to roll your own.